# Symfony2 - preferred_choices returns errors

Tags: symfony

I want to use `preferred_choices` in my entity form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('id','entity', array(
        'class'=>'GameShelf\UsersBundle\Entity\OwnState',
        'property' => 'name',
        'attr' => array('class'=>'chzn-select selectBig', 'data-placeholder'=>'Mam...'),
        'label' => ' ',
        'empty_value' => '',
        'preferred_choices' => array($options['selected'])
    ));
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'GameShelf\UsersBundle\Entity\OwnState',
        'selected' => 1
    );
}
```

But it returns an error: `Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given`. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace (int)1 with full entity object in getDefaultOptions()

(https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5277)